# AngularJS - wait for multiple resource queries to complete

Tags: angularjs

I have a single factory defined with ngResource:

```
App.factory('Account', function($resource) {
    return $resource('url', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET' }
    });
});
```

I am making multiple calls to the query method defined on this factory. The calls can happen asynchronously, but I need to wait for both calls to complete before continuing:

```
App.controller('AccountsCtrl', function ($scope, Account) {
    $scope.loadAccounts = function () {
        var billingAccounts = Account.query({ type: 'billing' });
        var shippingAccounts = Account.query({ type: 'shipping' });

        // wait for both calls to complete before returning
    };
});
```

Is there a way to do this with AngularJS factories defined with ngResource, similar to jQuery's $.when().then() functionality? I would prefer not to add jQuery to my current project.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

You'll want to use promises and [$q.all()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q).

Basically, you can use it to wrap all of your $resource or $http calls because they return promises.

```js
function doQuery(type) {
   var d = $q.defer();
   var result = Account.query({ type: type }, function() {
        d.resolve(result);
   });
   return d.promise;
}

$q.all([
   doQuery('billing'),
   doQuery('shipping')
]).then(function(data) {
   var billingAccounts = data[0];
   var shippingAccounts = data[1];

   //TODO: something...
});
```

Comment: Resources don't return promises, they return objects to be filled in the future. However in the *unstable* 1.1.3 version, resources also have `$then` property but do not expose any promise object. Exposing `$promise` completely would be in 1.1.4

Comment: @UmurKontacı This is unfortunately *not* in angular 1.1.4!

Comment: Details about the *resources are not promises problem* can be found in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/N5yBJvl7Pbg/C48oelQu6DgJ) and in [this pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2060#issuecomment-17026079).

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16076875/263061) shows how to write it once that is implemented.

Comment: It might be a bit cleaner to get `result` from the callback than from the assignment: `Account.query... function(result) { ...` instead of `var result = Account.query ... function() { ...`.

Comment: @nh2 ... you could do that of course! It's personal preference. I was just following the pattern set by the Angular team's examples. It's the same reference either way.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful and I believe it is the most sensible way to convert resources to promises in the current angular. It might be helpful to add that in the documentation of `$q`, which you linked to, it guarantees that the result array is in the same order as the promise array.

Comment: This was helpful especially the latest comment about guaranteeing the result array is in the same order as the promise array.

Answer (score 21):

I think a better solution is:

```
$q.all([
   Account.query({ type: 'billing' }).$promise,
   Account.query({ type: 'shipping' }).$promise
]).then(function(data) {
   var billingAccounts = data[0];
   var shippingAccounts = data[1];

   //TODO: something...
});
```

Comment: For me worked without $promise at the end... Just like: Account.query({ type: 'billing' }),
   Account.query({ type: 'shipping' })

Answer (score 13):

The solution from Ben Lesh is the best but it's not complete. If you need to handle error conditions--and, yes, you do--then you must use the `catch` method on the promise API like this:

```
$q.all([
   doQuery('billing'),
   doQuery('shipping')
]).then(function(data) {
   var billingAccounts = data[0];
   var shippingAccounts = data[1];

   //TODO: something...

}).catch(function(data) {

   //TODO: handle the error conditions...

}).finally(function () {

  //TODO: do final clean up work, etc...

});
```

If you don't define `catch` and all of your promises fail, then the `then` method won't ever execute and thus will probably leave your interface in a bad state.