# callback after async forEach AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I add a callback function after an async forEach Loop?

*Here is some better context:*

```
$scope.getAlbums = function(user, callback) {
    $scope.albumsList.forEach(function (obj, i) {
        $scope.getAlbum(user, obj.id, function(value){
            $scope.albums.push(value);
        });
    });
    // callback(); ???
};

$scope.getAlbums('guy123', function(){
    // forEach loop is all done!
    console.log($scope.albums)
});
```

**Controller:**

```
.controller('Filters', ['$scope','Imgur', function($scope, Imgur) {

    $scope.getAlbum = function(user, id, callback) {
        Imgur.album.get({user:user, id:id},    
            function(value) {
                return callback(value.data);
            }
        );
    }

    $scope.getAlbums = function(user, callback) {
        // Callback function at end of this forEach loop?
        // Request is async...
        $scope.albumsList.forEach(function (obj, i) {
            $scope.getAlbum(user, obj.id, function(value){
                $scope.albums.push(value);
            });
        });
    };
)]};
```

**Service:**

```
.factory('Imgur', function($resource) {
    return {
        album : $resource('https://api.imgur.com/3/account/:user/album/:id')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As Andrew said usage of `$q` and the deferred object should allow you to accomplish your goal.

You want to use `$q.all()`  This will make sure all of your promise objects are resolved and then you can call your call back in `.then()`

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $q, $http) {

    $scope.albumsList = [{
            id: 1,
            name: "11"
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: "22"
        }
    ];
    $scope.albums = [];
    $scope.getAlbum = function(user, id, callback) {
        return $http.get("https://api.imgur.com/3/account/" + user + "/album/" + id).success(
            function(value) {
                return callback(value.data);
            }
        );
    }
    $scope.getAlbums = function (user, callback) {
        var prom = [];
        $scope.albumsList.forEach(function (obj, i) {
            prom.push($scope.getAlbum(user, obj.id, function(value){
                $scope.albums.push(value);
            }));
        });
        $q.all(prom).then(function () {
            callback();
        });
    };
    $scope.getAlbums('guy123', function () {
        alert($scope.albums.length);
    });
}
```

**[Example with this on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/dwvQz/1/)**

Works but not with `$http` calls

With the deferred object you gain access to a promise where you can change successive `then()` calls together.  When you resolve the deferred object it will execute the foreach and then execute your call back function you supplied.  I tried to simplify your example a bit further so it would work in jsfiddle.

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $http, $q) {

    $scope.albumsList = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "11"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "22"
    }];
    $scope.albums = [];
    $scope.getAlbums = function (user, callback) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = deferred.promise;
        promise.then(function () {
            $scope.albumsList.forEach(function (obj, i) {
                $scope.albums.push(obj);
            });
        }).then(function () {
            callback();
        });
        deferred.resolve();
    };
    $scope.getAlbums('guy123', function () {
        alert($scope.albums.length);
    });
}
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/dwvQz/)**

**[A bit more reading on deferred and promises.](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2013/03/promises-and-deferred-objects-in-jquery.html)**

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, however, when I try with external resource data --- it doesn't hold it's promise ;) ... Could you please provide an example with any API data like twitter?

Comment: Since you are using the `$resource` that also returns a promise as well, you will need to modify your code so it chains the promises together and calling `resolve()` starts up the whole mechanism.

Comment: See update with example on jsfiddle that does simulated ajax post.

Comment: I've implimented your solution and pushed latest changes to project @ https://github.com/gigablox/angular-imgur-gallery/blob/master/app/js/controllers.js however the code I added still does not defer execution of those `$resource` calls I'm afraid :/ ... Did I miss something?

Comment: I misread the api documentation, `$resource` does not in fact return a promise object at all, you will need to use `$http` so you can utilize `$q.all()`  I read `$resource` is going to gain promise support but not until a later release.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. I'm going to give it a shot using the `$resource` promise support PR here: https://github.com/ashtuchkin/angular.js/commit/37dc1d3f74f81e9b0a4a7d9010bab8b266b49da3 Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531117/angularjs-1-1-3-resource-callback-error-and-success

Comment: That worked, you can see the new format in the answer I left if you're curious. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 5):

```
$scope.getAlbums = function(user, callback) {

        var promiseArr = [];
        $scope.albumsList.forEach(function (obj, i) {
            var anHttpPromise = 
            $scope.getAlbum(user, obj.id, function(value){
                $scope.albums.push(value);
            });
            promiseArr.push(anHttpPromise);
        });

        $q.all(promiseArr).then(function(){
            // This callback function will be called when all the promises are resolved.    (when all the albums are retrived)      
        })
    };

    $scope.getAlbum = function(user, id, callback) {
        var anHttpPromise = Imgur.album.get({user:user, id:id},    
            function(value) {
                return callback(value.data);
            }
        );
        return anHttpPromise;
    }
```

In the above code:

1. The `getAlbum` is made to return an promise.
2. Collecting an promise for each iteration of the `getAlbums` list
3. Once all the promises are collected, the promise array is passed to
   `$q.all`
4. The `$q.all` method instead returns an final promise whose callback
   function will be triggered once all the promises in the array are
   resolved.

Comment: I've implimented your solution and pushed latest changes to project @ https://github.com/gigablox/angular-imgur-gallery/blob/master/app/js/controllers.js However it still does not defer promise. Mabye I missed something?

Answer (score 4):

Using the `$resource` promise [**PR commit**](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/angular.js/commit/37dc1d3f74f81e9b0a4a7d9010bab8b266b49da3) slated for 1.1.3, I was able to wrap `$resource` calls with $q and control the flow of their async behavoir.

```
$scope.getAlbum = function(user, id, callback) {
    var promise = Imgur.album.get({user:user, id:id}).$promise.then(
        function( value ){
            return callback(value.data);
        },
        function( error ){
            //Something went wrong!
        }
    )
    return promise;
}

$scope.getAlbums = function(user, callback) {
    var prom = [];
    $scope.albumsList.forEach(function (obj, i) {
        var promise =
        $scope.getAlbum(user, obj.id, function(value){
            $scope.albums.push(value);
        });
        prom.push(promise);

    });

    $q.all(prom).then(function () {
        callback();
    });
};

$scope.getAlbums(user, function(){
    // Totally works, bro.
    console.log($scope.albums);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like deferred [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q) and specifically chaining promises could be useful here.

Comment: Could you share an example in context with this problem :) ?

Comment: Please see Mark's answer above.