# How can I maintain a pristine/dirty cache in angular $resource?

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I have a model given by $resource. I want to maintain a cache of what has changed and not, so I can:

- easily revert back to pristine mode (discard changes)
- send only changed items (e.g. using `PATCH`)

This is discussed a bit here: [Partial Updates (aka PATCH) using a $resource based service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258334/partial-updates-aka-patch-using-a-resource-based-service)

It is easy to extend `$resource` to have other methods, e.g. `$patch` and `getDirty()` or `getChanged()`. But for this to work, I need to catch the original fields when loaded, so I know their clean state.

How can I capture the originally loaded fields?

My intent was to have it stored somewhere on the object itself.

Also open to better ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two approaches here.

1. Use the `transformResponse` of `$resource` (see [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource)) in order to set up your custom tracking variables on the returned object.
2. The `$pristine`/`$dirty` tracking mechanism is already implemented in [`ngFormController`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController), so you should really use it.

Comment: `transformResponse` is a nice idea. That works well. Dirty tracking in a form makes sense, but what I really want is to be able to call `$patch()` instead of `$save()`. Putting that in the form means I do it in the controller, which means in every controller. Since the form is tied to the underlying model, I would prefer to just do `item.patch()`. But to do that, I need to recreate pristine/dirty in the resource itself.

Comment: You can use a service that returns a "ready-to-patch" object and call it every time, if you don't want to re-implement the dirty logic.

Comment: that's exactly what I was trying to do, but by wrapping `$resource`. Then all I have to do is call `item.$patch()`. Can you whip up a fiddle or gist of an example of your ready-to-patch object and how it differs from my idea? Love to get a better one.

Comment: Set up a `factory` that returns your `$resource`, then add custom methods and implementations to it. See http://kirkbushell.me/angular-js-using-ng-resource-in-a-more-restful-manner/.

Comment: I did something very similar. My only issue is saving the pristine state on load, so that my custom `$patch()` will only send the right resources. Take a look at https://gist.github.com/deitch/9170318

Comment: Well, you could simply clone the object when receiving it (or instantiating it) and then do recursive checks for equality on patch.

Comment: Oh, clone as a pristine patch makes a lot of sense. I will see if I can trap that using `transformResponse`. That should help with a `GET`. I'll need to think of something for instantiation. Actually, that is not hard, since there is no existing state.

Comment: This would be *so* much easier if they just supported this directly in ngResource

Comment: Yeah, `ngResource` is a lot like `ngRoute`, a simple module to get you started. About the tracking system, I actually did something like this for knockout.js 2 years ago or something like that: https://github.com/frapontillo/knockout-rest.

Comment: What a headache, just to properly support `PATCH` with updating changed fields.

Comment: This worked, although resource `interceptor` in 1.2.x+ worked even more easily. Now I need to figure out where to store the pristine data...

Comment: ... since ngResource saves everything to `POST`.

Comment: You could use transformRequest and clear the dirty information upon sending the data.

Comment: Feh, not so great. If you use `interceptor` (which only manages the response), it still does its usual stuff. `transformRequest`, though, comes *instead* of the usual angular handling, so you lose any JSON transformation it does.