# Bindonce with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, bindonce

I've used `Bindonce` to improve performance of `ng-repeat`.

But I have one problem : Collection that is used from `ng-repeat` is filled with data a bit later (request data from API takes some time), so it's empty, cause updating is prevented by `Bindonce`.

How can I specify to wait response from server and then make binding?

---

Code example :

In controller I have array `$scope.requests = [];`

It is initialized with factory

```
$scope.requests = CurrentUserData.getRequests();
```

I've red about promises and thought that this code can help :

```
CurrentUserData.getRequests()
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.requests = response;
            });
```

But I receive an error

> angular.js:11655 TypeError: CurrentUserData.getRequests(...).then is not a function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [callback after async forEach AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429832/callback-after-async-foreach-angularjs)

Comment: can you post your code for `getRequests` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CurrentUserData.getRequests(...)` is not returning a promise.

If you will be using the code

```
CurrentUserData.getRequests()
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.requests = response;
            });
```

then the line `$scope.requests = response` should be changed to `$scope.requests = response.data`

Having said that you can make use of original code

```
$scope.myData = CurrentUserData.getRequests();
$scope.$watch(myData,
              function(newVal, oldVal){
                     $scope.requests = newVal
              });
```

Answer (score 2):

Most probable cause: your function `getRequests` in `CurrectUserData` doesn't return a promise, it should be `return $http.get('/the/url/etc')`