# Angular js call back after multiple http calls complete with foreach

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am sending multiple HTTP  calls to update items inside foreach loop and need a callback after all request complete. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429832/callback-after-async-foreach-angularjs) but didn't help.

My code:

```
$q.all(_($scope.students.items).each(function(item) {
   $scope.student.update(); //this is an http call
})).then(function() {
   // I need a callback need here
   alert("complete"); //should be shown after all students get updated but it is
                      // called before all network calls got complete
});
```

Here is generic update function

```
self.update = function(item, callback) {
   that.post(item, self.getUrl("update") , function(err, data) {
      if (self.formatter) {
         data = self.formatter(data);
      }
      callback(err, data);
   });
 };
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Post here a code of `$scope.student.update()` function.

Comment: why are you calling a general `$scope.student.update();` without usign the `item`?

Comment: this is an generic call to api service also i can use callback after updating this student if it help in my problem.As follow  $scope.student.update(function(){callback here})

Comment: @Rhumborl No i need item to set student properties i have removed the code to keep my question simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss a `return` keyword in `update()` function because it has to return a promise (and, of course, `that.post()` function has to return a promise too):

```
self.update = function(item, callback) {
   return that.post(item, self.getUrl("update") , function(err, data) {
      if (self.formatter) {
         data = self.formatter(data);
      }
      callback(err, data);
   });
 };
```

Then this should work:

```
var promises = [];
_($scope.students.items).each(function(item) {
   promises.push($scope.student.update());
})
$q.all(promises).then(function() {
   alert("complete");
});
```

Comment: @jitender it really depends how a function `$scope.student.update();` looks like - it has to return promise... I also don't understand why doesn't this function take any parameter?

Comment: @Akarienta This is  an generic service something very big to explain

Comment: @jitender the important thing is what does this function return

Comment: This function will return student model after update

Comment: @jitender and is it promise? I think the problem is in `$scope.student.update();` function; not in the code you have posted

Comment: There is no promise inside that service .how i can return because its work for others too like $scope.course.update etc

Comment: @jitender this is the reason why we need to see code of `$scope.student.update();` function

Comment: self.update = function(item, callback) {
                that.post(item, self.getUrl("update") , function(err, data) {
                    if (self.formatter) {
                        data = self.formatter(data);
                    }
                    callback(err, data);
                });
            };

Comment: @jitender place `return` keyword before `that.post` and then try my code again

Comment: @jitender yeah, just go deeper - every function in the chain has to return a promise, just check a `that.post()` now and make it to return a promise (`$http.post()` returns a promise)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117221/discussion-between-akarienta-and-jitender).

Comment: @Akarienta Thanks its start working for me as i go deeper and use to return from every function in the chain

Comment: @jitender no problem glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

You could try this as well by using `map`

```
$q.all(_($scope.students.items).map(function(item) {
  item.update();
})).then(function() {
  alert("complete");
});
```

> I have updated the code here with the below snippet. I have used some methods that return simple promises. Includes two ways you could do this.

- Pushing promises into an array and using q.all
- Using map with q.all

```js
angular.module('demoApp', []).controller('DemoController', function($scope, $q, $timeout) {
  var a = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    console.log('Executing a');
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise;
  };
  var b = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    console.log('Executing b');
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise;
  };
  var c = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    console.log('Executing c');
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise;
  };
  var f = [{
    call: a
  }, {
    call: b
  }, {
    call: c
  }];

  $scope.mapTest = function() {
    $q.all(f.map(function(item) {
      return item.call();
    })).then(function() {
      console.log("complete");
    });

  };
  $scope.promisePush = function() {
    var promises = [];
    angular.forEach(f, function(item) {
      promises.push(item.call());
    });
    $q.all(promises).then(function() {
      console.log('complete');
    });
  };


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="demoApp">
  <div ng-controller="DemoController">
    <button ng-click="mapTest()">Q.all using map</button>
    <button ng-click="promisePush()">Q.all using promise push</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: After all requests are complete

Comment: @Srijith it should be `return item.update()`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks its help me a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
$q.all(_.map($scope.students.items, function(item) {
   return item.update();
})).then(function() {
   //everything has completed
});
```

The update function on each item in `$scope.student.items` will have to return the promise for this to work. Something like:

```
function update() {
   return $http( ... );
}
```

Comment: Not work its show alert although all request all pending in networks

Answer (score 0):

You should not send the same ajax in foreach. This should be single ajax and update should be done in callback, so send one ajax like "studentsUpdate" and in response do foreach on studenst collection and update objects data. Good practice is less ajax calls.