# Resolve factory with result from other factory

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

Before a state is loaded, I wish to resolve a factory using the data from another factory.

My situation:

```
"taskVariables": function (getTask, getTaskVariables, $stateParams) {
      getTask.get({'task': $stateParams.taskId}).success(function(data) {
         console.log("I'm here");
         return getTaskVariables.get({'processInstanceId': data.processInstanceId});
      });
      return false;
      console.log("I have failed you master")
  },
```

Factory:

```
.factory('getTask', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('api/task/get/:task', {'user': '@user', 'task': '@task'}, {
            'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                transformResponse: function (data) {
                    data = angular.fromJson(data);
                    return data;
                }
            }
        })
    })
```

The thing is that I think that one factory is loading faster than the other, thus the data will be undefined on page load, but that is just me speculating.

Is there a way to achieve this with maybe a promise or some kind?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Because I return a $resource I cannot declare a success- nor a failure function, so you need to change it by giving it a $promise, followed by a then:

```
"taskVariables": function (getTask, getTaskVariables, $stateParams) {
       return getTask.get({'task': $stateParams.taskId}).$promise.then(function(data) {
              return getTaskVariables.get({'processInstanceId': data.processInstanceId});
       });
}
```

reffering to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531117/resource-callback-error-and-success) question/answer

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting to return the initial getTask promise.

```
"taskVariables": function (getTask, getTaskVariables, $stateParams) {
    return getTask.get({'task': $stateParams.taskId}).success(function(data) {
        console.log("I'm here");
        return getTaskVariables.get({'processInstanceId': data.processInstanceId});
    });
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately it is not working :(

Comment: Reaching the resolving factory, neither the success or the failed state is returned, it is not being logged

Comment: Place a [debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#debugging-javascript) in your code and walk through it, is getTask defined ? is getTask.get a promise ?

Comment: Apologies for not telling you that I use a $resource and not an $http call in my factory. It works now with a $promise, as I found out you cannot have a .success with a $resource