# Angular - Multiple $http.get Requests for Data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the best approach to take when making multiple calls to an API for data needed in the same view?

For example, you have multiple select boxes which need to contain data pulled in from outside the app, all in the same view.

Is there a more elegant solution than simply firing them all at once in your controller? Such as the following

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($service) { 

   $service.getDataOne().then(function(response) {
      $scope.dataOne = response;
   }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
   });

   $service.getDataTwo().then(function(response) {
      $scope.dataTwo = response;
   }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
   })
});
```

etc...with each service function performing a $http.get request.

While this works, I feel there is probably a more elegant solution.

Any thoughts as always is much appreciated.

Comment: You can use [q.all()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), as it accepts an array of promises that will only be resolved when all of the promises have been resolved. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15300364/2679750)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [q.all()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), as it accepts an array of promises that will only be resolved when all of the promises have been resolved.

```
$q.all([
      $service.getDataOne(),
      $service.getDataTwo()
    ]).then(function(data){
      $scope.dataOne = data[0];
      $scope.dataTwo = data[1];
 });
```

> If you look at the link, `q.All()` is at the very bottom of the page

Comment: Mark, why should he include a whole external q library rather than use angular's own $q? Don't you think he should use angular's version?

Comment: @ChrisL Where do you see me telling OP to load an external library?

Comment: I think the syntax for Angular is $q . There is another q library which angular's is modeled after. https://github.com/kriskowal/q that is q without the $ . If I am wrong I appologize, but this could be confusing... Although I agree with your answer if you meant angular's version!

Comment: @ChrisL Ah! The `$` got trimmed when I was formatting my answer haha, thanks. Great catch!

Comment: You just call this like it is in the controller?

Comment: No problem @user2085143 !

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the $q service.

http://jsfiddle.net/Zenuka/pHEf9/21/

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

```
function TodoCtrl($scope, $q, $timeout) {
function createPromise(name, timeout, willSucceed) {
    $scope[name] = 'Running';
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $timeout(function() {
        if (willSucceed) {
            $scope[name] = 'Completed';
            deferred.resolve(name);
        } else {
            $scope[name] = 'Failed';
            deferred.reject(name);
        }
    }, timeout * 1000);
    return deferred.promise;
}

// Create 5 promises
var promises = [];
var names = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    var willSucceed = true;
    if (i == 2) willSucceed = false;
    promises.push(createPromise('Promise' + i, i, willSucceed));
}

// Wait for all promises    
$scope.Status1 = 'Waiting';
$scope.Status2 = 'Waiting';
$q.all(promises).then(
    function() { 
        $scope.Status1 = 'Done'; 
    }, 
    function() { 
        $scope.Status1 = 'Failed'; 
    }
).finally(function() {
    $scope.Status2 = 'Done waiting';
});
}
```

Credit: Code shamelessly stolen from unknown creator of fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

If it for loading the looku pdata for all the dropdowns, I would make one call to get all the lookup data in one single payload. Something like this. Each property value is an array of items for each dropdown.

```
{
    "eventMethods": [
        {
            "name": "In Person",
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "Phone",
            "id": 2
        }
    ],
    "statuses": [
        {
            "name": "Cancelled",
            "id": 42
        },
        {
            "name": "Complete",
            "id": 41
        }
    ]
}
```