# resolve multiple promises in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

Here is my factory which gets data from an API and stores each data to a SQLLite database.

```
team.factory('dataSync', function($q,$http,$timeout,$cordovaSQLite ){
    return {
        getData:function(){
            var q = $q.defer();
             $http.get(api+'/sync/').then(function(response){
                q.resolve(response);
            },function(error){
                q.reject();
            })
            return q.promise;

        },

        saveData:function(){
            var q= $q.defer();

            this.getData().then(function(result){
                var data= result.data;
                var sharing = data.sharing;
                var help = data.help;
                var message = data.message;
                var questions = data.question;

                var promises = [];

                angular.forEach(sharing, function(value, index) { 
                        console.log(value);
                    var sharingsql="INSERT INTO sharing (id,content_order,content ,last_modified)VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

                     $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,sharingsql,[value.id,value.content_order,value.content,value.last_modified]).then(function(result){
                        console.log(result.insertId);
                        //q.resolve(true);
                     },function(error){
                        console.log(error.message);
                     })
                });
                angular.forEach(help, function(value, index) { 
                    console.log(value.message);
                    var helpsql="INSERT INTO help (id,message,message_position,last_modified)VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

                     $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,helpsql,[value.id,value.message,value.message_position,value.last_modified]).then(function(result){
                        console.log(result.insertId);
                     },function(error){
                        console.log(error.message);
                     })
                });

                    angular.forEach(message, function(value, index) { 
                    var messagesql="INSERT INTO messages (id,message,message_position,last_modified_date)VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

                     $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,messagesql,[value.id,value.message,value.message_position,value.last_modified]).then(function(result){
                        console.log(result.insertId);
                     },function(error){
                        console.log(error.message);
                     })
                });

                    angular.forEach(questions, function(value, index) { 
                    console.log(value.id+' '+index);
                    var questionsql="INSERT INTO questions (id,question_status,questions,question_order,last_modified)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";

                     $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,questionsql,[value.id,value.question_status,value.question,value.question_order,value.last_modified]).then(function(result){
                        console.log(result.insertId);
                     },function(error){
                        console.log(error.message);
                     })
                });


                    $timeout(function(){

                    },2000).then(function(){

                        //q.resolve(true);
                    })


            },function(error){
                q.reject();
            });
            return q.promise;
        }

    }
});
```

The call to `$cordovaSQLite.execute` returns a promise.

I want to return `true` after all the promises are resolved. How can I resolve all the promises that are resolved in each loop?

When I searched about this I found `$q.all` as an answer. Then I have read some tutorials about this but cannot implement here.

Comment: Avoid the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - wait for multiple resource queries to complete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299850/angularjs-wait-for-multiple-resource-queries-to-complete)

Comment: Yes, `$q.all` is the answer. Please show us how you tried to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes use [`$q.all()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all). Push the promises into the array, but remove the `.then()` callbacks. [`Promise.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) returns a promise so if the `.then()` callbacks are not removed, they would need to be updated to return the arguments (i.e. `result`).

```
promises.push($cordovaSQLite.execute(db,sharingsql,[value.id,value.content_order,value.content,value.last_modified]))
```

Then use `$q.all(promises)` by calling [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) on it, where `true` can be returned:

```
$q.all(promises)
  .then(function(responses) {
    //all promises have been resolved
    return true;
  })
```

See a demonstration in [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CRVDFa).

Comment: why $q.all(promises).then(function(res){console.log(res)}) gives undefined?

Comment: @SurajKhanal it is difficult to answer that question without seeing what is in `promises`. I updated the [plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/CRVDFa) to match your original code better (i.e. using a factory provider).

Answer (score 2):

put all promises into an array and then use `$q.all(yourArray).`

Here is your updated code - You don't need to use `$q.defer()` since `$http` already returns a promise - and all your `$cordovaSQLite` promises will be resolved by themselves

```
team.factory('dataSync', function($q,$http,$timeout,$cordovaSQLite ){
    return {
        getData:function(){
            return $http.get(api+'/sync/').then(function(response){
                return response;
            },function(error){
                $q.reject();
            })
        },
        saveData:function(){
            return this.getData().then(function(result){
                var data= result.data;
                var sharing = data.sharing;
                var help = data.help;
                var message = data.message;
                var questions = data.question;

                var promises = [];

                angular.forEach(sharing, function(value, index) { 
                        console.log(value);
                    var sharingsql="INSERT INTO sharing (id,content_order,content ,last_modified)VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

                     promises.push($cordovaSQLite.execute(db,sharingsql,[value.id,value.content_order,value.content,value.last_modified]).then(function(result){
                        console.log(result.insertId);
                        //q.resolve(true);
                     },function(error){
                        console.log(error.message);
                     }));
                });
                angular.forEach(help, function(value, index) { 
                    console.log(value.message);
                    var helpsql="INSERT INTO help (id,message,message_position,last_modified)VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

                     promises.push($cordovaSQLite.execute(db,helpsql,[value.id,value.message,value.message_position,value.last_modified]).then(function(result){
                        console.log(result.insertId);
                     },function(error){
                        console.log(error.message);
                     }));
                });

                    angular.forEach(message, function(value, index) { 
                    var messagesql="INSERT INTO messages (id,message,message_position,last_modified_date)VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

                     promises.push($cordovaSQLite.execute(db,messagesql,[value.id,value.message,value.message_position,value.last_modified]).then(function(result){
                        console.log(result.insertId);
                     },function(error){
                        console.log(error.message);
                     }));
                });

                    angular.forEach(questions, function(value, index) { 
                    console.log(value.id+' '+index);
                    var questionsql="INSERT INTO questions (id,question_status,questions,question_order,last_modified)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";

                     promises.push($cordovaSQLite.execute(db,questionsql,[value.id,value.question_status,value.question,value.question_order,value.last_modified]).then(function(result){
                        console.log(result.insertId);
                     },function(error){
                        console.log(error.message);
                     }));
                });
                return $q.all(promises);
            },function(error){
                return $q.reject();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This way when you call `saveData()` it will return a promise that will be resolved once all your `$cordovaSQLite` are resolved, and you can use `.then()` to do what you want after all that happen.

**Note:**
I think all error handlers can be removed and use only one "catch" function

Comment: I think getData could even just be `return $http.get(api+'/sync/')`

Comment: I think all error handlers can be removed and use only one "catch" function - but I am not completely sure. I prefered to leave them - but I will add this as a comment

Comment: As long as it isn't overriden by an interceptor, the error can be catched the same both ways.

Comment: Thanks @Gonzalo.- for your answer. I know many answer to this type of questions are already there but i cant implement after reading those answer. I will accept this answer .

Comment: The OP didn't state that the returned values need to be used but if so, the `.then()` callbacks would need to be updated to return the arguments.... otherwise the data won't get passed back.