# Angularjs asychronous calls between two functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to implement following scenario in angularjs please suggest me best way for thia.

1. I have written one method named 'CollectAll()' which contains block of code for http get records. This block of code i have written inside for loop to execute it 10times.
2. Another method named 'saveAll()' which sends data to backend using httppost which requires above collected data from first method.

These two functions i want to execute one after another. Because second is dependent on first. But first function has many http calls and combine result i want to pass it to sexond method as input for http post request.

Please suggest me best solution for this.

Thanks.

Comment: What are the return types of those methods? Are they promises or observables?

Can you post some sample code?

Comment: These two function returns promise

Comment: Why don't you post your code instead of describing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - wait for multiple resource queries to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299850/angularjs-wait-for-multiple-resource-queries-to-complete)

Answer (score 0):

Check out AngularJS's $q for resolving promises in groups. That should be all you need if I am understanding the issue correctly. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q